# what's the relationship of tensor and multivector

Tags: tensors, geometric-algebras

what's the relationship of multivector in geometric algebra and tensor? Is tensor a subset of multivector?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every multivector corresponds to a tensor, but not every tensor corresponds to a multivector.

The classic picture of a tensor is a linear map, acting on any number of vectors and dual vectors, to produce a scalar.  Inspired by exterior and geometric algebra, you can say a tensor acts on any number of vector or dual vector blades.

For example, rotation operators can be viewed as tensors:  let $\underline R(a)$ be some rotation, then there exists a tensor $R(a,b) = \underline R(a) \cdot b$.  Because there is such a close correspondence, it's not uncommon to refer to the rotation map itself as a tensor.

You can extend the rotation map to act on blades, and therefore whole multivectors, through addition in the geometric algebra, but the rotation map itself isn't an *element* of the geometric algebra--it's not a multivector.

So, even in geometric algebra, we have need or use of linear maps, of general tensors.

How can you build a tensor from a general multivector?  Through any function that is linear in all its arguments.  A simple way is to consider a general multivector $M$.  For the sake of an example, let's say $M$ is composed of blades grade-4 or less.  Then you can build a tensor, $T$, such that

$$T(a, b, c, d) = \langle M abcd \rangle_0$$

which is linear in all its arguments $a, b, c, d$ and produces a scalar.

For this reason, you might refer to a multivector in general as a tensor, too, since there is such a close and obvious correspondence between a multivector and an associated linear map.

Answer (score 1):

These resources explaining how to represent multivectors as tensors might be helpful or interesting to you (or those with similar questions):

http://www2.ic.uff.br/~laffernandes/teaching/2013.1/topicos_ag/lecture_18%20-%20Tensor%20Representation.pdf

https://www.docdroid.net/uwfvUxE/tensor-representation-of-geometric-algebra.pdf.html